# Magento 1.9.1.0 indexer fails after upgrade

Tags: php, magento

When I call `php indexer.php --reindexall` from the shell I get the follwing error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getProcessesCollection() on a non-object in /var/www/xxxxxx/public_html/shell/indexer.php on line 58

I have just updated Magento to 1.9.1.0. Everything seems to work just fine, but no products are showing in the frontend as the indexer does not work.

It does not seem to be a common error, so I'm quite stuck at the moment.

Comment: When did this error start?